# Docusign is getting crashed after showing location permission alert in native iOS app

Tags: ios, docusignapi, docusignconnect

Our iOS native application is using Docusign native SDK 2.5.2 version. The Docusign gets loaded and when I click continue for signing, it pops up a location permission alert and the Docusign window gets closed immediately. Please let me know how to fix this issue.

Comment: do you use an iframe to load DocuSign UI inside an iframe?

Comment: Did you also try using `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`? Another option with `NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription` and
`NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`?